# No Sound using WINEASIO/JACK with MuLab

Tags: drivers, sound, wine

My preferred music studio software is MuLab, and I have gotten it to work under WINE, and the default MME output works perfectly. The problem being the WineASIO driver does not produce any sound with Jack, and the driver insists on running at 48000 hz. I have specifically set the Jack GUI plug in to run at 44100 hz and use the audio output that I am actively using, but nothing. I have a feeling this might be similar to another problem already asked before, but I couldn't find my exact problem.

I have restarted Jack many times, and swapping to the low latency driver didn't help. WineASIO appears to be installed correctly.

I feel like I am missing something, any advice?

Comment: You have checked the Wine site to see if this is a supported software and if it has any limitations? https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1081

Comment: I was not aware that Wine has a compatibility list on their website! That will prove useful. As for MuLab, it does not appear to be on the list. Like I said, the software runs just fine by default, its the WineASIO driver, or something related to it, that is not working properly. I vaguely remember getting it to work a long time ago, and that and the fact that the driver is technically showing up tells me that it is possible